# counter_cache not updating on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Item` with a `has_one` relationship to its `canonical_item_id`. This should return the `canonical_item` when present. This is working fine.

```
has_one :canonical_item, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :id, primary_key: :canonical_id
belongs_to :canonical_item, counter_cache: true
```

I try to set `belongs_to :canonical_item, counter_cache: true` to update the `canonical_item.items_counter` counter but it is not updating. I also notice that when adding  I lost the association to the `cannonical_item`

```
Item.last.canonical_item
=> nil
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if this is because of methods and/or callbacks for your `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations overriding each other. It seems an unlikely situation that you need both, though.

If what you need is a `belongs_to` association:

```
create_table :items do |t|
  t.integer :canonical_item_id
end

create_table :canonical_items do |t|
  t.integer :items_count, :default => 0
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :canonical_items, :counter_cache => true
end

class CanonicalItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

If what you need is a `has_one` association, the DB structure as it is wouldn't allow more than one `Item` for a `CanonicalItem`, so it doesn't make much sense to count associated `Item` records. You can simply check if there is a value for `:item_id`.

```
create_table :items do |t|
end

create_table :canonical_items do |t|
  t.integer :item_id
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :canonical_item, :dependent => :nullify
end

class CanonicalItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The field for cache counters is `items_count` not `items_counter`.

Make sure that field exists in your database.

Comment: Try renaming the `belongs_to` symbol to be different to the `has_one`. They appear to both currently be `canonical_item`.